# How to clear v-autocomplete (multiple) search input after selecting the checkbox in the drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have multiple v-autocomplete component from Vuetify. Currently, for example if enter in search input "Cali" and check "California" value, "Cali" value still exist in search input. I need to clear entered value. For current, search value cleared when closing dropdown list, but I need clear it when I select checkbox.

```
<v-autocomplete
        v-model="select"
        :loading="loading"
        :items="items"
        :search-input.sync="search"
        cache-items
        class="mx-3"
        flat
        hide-no-data
        hide-details
        label="What state are you from?"
        solo-inverted
        multiple
      ></v-autocomplete>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      items: [],
      search: null,
      select: null,
      states: [
        'Alabama',
        'Alaska',
        'American Samoa',
        'Arizona',
        'Arkansas',
        'California',
        'Colorado',
        'Connecticut',
        'Delaware',
        'District of Columbia',
        'Federated States of Micronesia',
        'Florida',
        'Georgia',
        'Guam',
        'Hawaii',
        'Idaho',
        'Illinois',
        'Indiana',
        'Iowa',
        'Kansas',
        'Kentucky',
        'Louisiana',
        'Maine',
        'Marshall Islands',
        'Maryland',
        'Massachusetts',
        'Michigan',
        'Minnesota',
        'Mississippi',
        'Missouri',
        'Montana',
        'Nebraska',
        'Nevada',
        'New Hampshire',
        'New Jersey',
        'New Mexico',
        'New York',
        'North Carolina',
        'North Dakota',
        'Northern Mariana Islands',
        'Ohio',
        'Oklahoma',
        'Oregon',
        'Palau',
        'Pennsylvania',
        'Puerto Rico',
        'Rhode Island',
        'South Carolina',
        'South Dakota',
        'Tennessee',
        'Texas',
        'Utah',
        'Vermont',
        'Virgin Island',
        'Virginia',
        'Washington',
        'West Virginia',
        'Wisconsin',
        'Wyoming'
      ]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    search (val) {

      val && val !== this.select && this.querySelections(val)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    querySelections (v) {

      this.loading = true
      // Simulated ajax query
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.items = this.states.filter(e => {
          return (e || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((v || '').toLowerCase()) > -1
        })
        this.loading = false
      }, 500)
    }
  }
})
```

I want to clear value in search input after selecting value in dropdown list.
Here is codepen example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZMKeL

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add watcher for select value and reset `search-input`:

```
watch: {
  select() {
    this.search = ''
  }
```

Or react on one of the events:
`<v-autocomplete @input="search = ''"`
 or
`<v-autocomplete @change="search = ''"`

---

Watch `select` because of `v-model` value (`<v-autocomplete v-model="select"`), and change
`this.search` because of `search-input.sync` value (`:search-input.sync="search"`).

Comment: Thank you!!! I added this.search = ' ' to @change event, and it works as i expected.

Comment: In my case I had to use `$nextTick`, otherwise it would not work.

Comment: Just in case anyone else tried, I set search to `null` and it didn't work. Must be empty string.